# Custom Registration Events

Tags: customer, customer-group, register

I have a custom db table called "membership". The table appears as below:

```
membership_no(pk) | bronze | silver | gold

1000001           |   no   |   no   |  yes
1000002           |   yes  |   no   |  no
```

What id like to do is:

1. Add a custom field to registration form that asks for membership number.
2. Validate membership number input against database and if value exists get that row.

3 Assign the customer to a customer group dependent on membership type of the selected row?

Any ideas? (using v1.7.0.2)

Thanks

Stefan

Answer (score -1):

I am working on this exact issue. So far this is what I have figured out.

1. Override `code/core/mage/customer/etc/config.xml` and add the `customer_id` fieldset(aka membership_no) , make sure you are in the `customer_account` scope.
2. add the new field to

`app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/persistant/customer/form/registration.phtml`

I am on v1.14.0 so I do not know if they had started using the 'persistant' scheme yet.

Still looking into validation